# How to connect back to previous windows form in visual c++ 2010 and hide current windows form

Tags: visual-c++, windows-forms-designer

Actually i am beginner to visual c++ haven't worked before on this platform. I am a quite beginner So I am made a Form1 that

this->Hide();
Teacherspanel^ obj = gcnew Teacherspanel();
obj->ShowDialog();

which hides form1 and starts form2 
I want to go back to form1, Kindly help me in this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, obj->ShowDialog() is modal and should block any further progress.  After it, you should be able to call this->Show().

In other words:

```
this->Hide();
Teacherspanel^ obj = gcnew Teacherspanel();
obj->ShowDialog(); // does not proceed past here until Teacherspanel closes
this->Show();
```

Commentary: No one recommends using C++ with WinForms or other .NET.  If you want to do .NET, use C#.  If you want to do C++, do straight API or MFC programming.